# submit multiple forms with p:commandbutton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to submit multiple forms with one submit button. I have multiple forms because each p:fileUpload needs an own form (when in advanced mode).

Here's the code for my submit button:

```
<h:form id="form1">...</h:form>
<h:form id="form2">...</h:form>
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" widgetVar="saveButtonBottom"
    action="#{bean.submit}" ajax="false"
    process=":form1,:form2,@this" />
</h:form>
```

It does call bean.submit(), but it does not process the other forms. Maybe my understanding of processing is wrong, but I thought if I put a form into "process", then it will be submitted.

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 7):

That's the limitation of HTML. Only the input data containing within the current form (wherein the command is been invoked) will be sent to the server side. As to the `process` attribute, that only identifies which part(s) of *that* submitted data must be processed by JSF after they have arrived.

> *Any idea how to make it work?*

Put all related data in the same form. Use if necessary just a single `<p:fileUpload>` with multiple file selection support.

Comment: I have one file upload field with single, and one with multiple file selection support. They're for different purposes, so I cannot merge them.

Comment: This is the limitation of plain HTML, but it's not the limitation of JavaScript. Why is it affecting JSF 2? Will there ever be full-AJAX JSF 3, to keep up with modern world?

Comment: Is that still valid? I have somehow the impression that with ajax style handling it can read the entire DOM tree, and send any portion of the page, even outside the current form.

Comment: Adding a `partialSubmit="true"` in PrimeFaces makes it behave differently. Then in situations multiple forms **CAN** be submitted (at least the data). Don't think this is by design but more likely side effect that should **not be relied on**

Comment: @Kukeltje: that's indeed unspecified behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Place this inside form2:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="sendAjaxicalPGfilter"
update="form2:minMaxTable"
action="#{OptimizationSettingsBean.handleProductGroupChange}"  />
```

call this on form1 command button

```
<p:commandButton value="Done"
oncomplete="selectedSettingDlg.hide();" onstart="sendAjaxicalPGfilter();"
ajax="true" action="#{CreateSourcingPlanBean.dummy}" 
                            update=":form1:assignmentList" >
                </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just saw your answer now. I will try both yours and rootkit's answer next week, and tell you what worked (the project was active last summer, so I have to find time to get back to it first). From what I understand, both answers are rather similar, only that you suggest using a remoteCommand instead of triggering a button submit.

Answer (score 4):

in your

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" widgetVar="saveButtonBottom"
    action="#{bean.submit}" ajax="false"
    process=":form1,:form2,@this" />
```

add the attribute: `partialSubmit="true"` and chance `ajax="false"` to `ajax="true"`

```
<p:commandButton partialSubmit="true" value="Save" widgetVar="saveButtonBottom"
    action="#{bean.submit}" ajax="true"
    process=":form1,:form2,@this" />
```

Comment: It did in my case, I did not tried with this example here. let me saw you. Please look at the next answer i did. I am not very familiar with stackoverflow, sorry.

Comment: I would like to put all my code here but I really don't know how to do it. I would like to explain a bit how I did it though. I have a form that contains some buttons. I have another form that contains editatble fields. Without the partialSubmit = true this did not work. I found it also in a forum. So if you want to downvote go ahead, I just say it did work for me.

Comment: If it works, there is no need to downvote (but please remove your other 'answer'). And also no need to post full code if you are sure adding `partialSubmit="true"` made the difference. It is only very illogical that something to reduce the number of fields submitted in one form can also be used to submit fields from multiple forms. [The source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.ajax.js) might prove why this works... Will investigate later, or you can do that and add to it to your answer.

Comment: I investigated and it indeed seems (not actually tested/debugged) that for doing a partial submit, PrimeFaces resolves **all** components that are under each of the id's specified under the `process` attribute. So adding multiple forms adds all inputs in all forms as done above. BUT... You may **not** set 'ajax' to false which you did not do in your other answer. So in fact this answer is **not good** but can be made good by adding some info about the ajax to it...

Comment: Thank you for this improvement. I will continue investigating and testing .

Answer (score 3):

As BalusC correctly pointed out you can only submit one form in one request. However, you can invoke multiple requests with one button click:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" widgetVar="saveButtonBottom"
    action="#{bean.submit}" ajax="false" onstart="form1submitbutton.getJQ().click();form2submitbutton.getJQ().click()"
    process="@form" />
```

You have to realize this will result in multiple simultaneous requests being processed by your server, and there are no guarantees as to request processing order. This can make validation and backend data processing tricky. You could try to work around that by using oncomplete handler and fire form submissions in sequence this way, but still this means your forms data will be sent to the server one-by-one.

Also, the above approach will only work if your forms are submitted via ajax.

Comment: Depends. If you use the sample code above it will be simultaneous. If you use oncomplete handler then you can do it in sequential order.