# jsf Press a hidden Button by javascript from another form

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two forms. Form "form2" have several buttons. When one of this buttons is pressed i want to press a hidden button in my form "form1" to submit it and update the whole form.

But i still having the problem when i press the Button in my form2 the values are not submitted. Is the javascript function wrong or have Primefaces/JSF something to do this better?

I'm using Primefaces 5.

My view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div>
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:inputText value="#{myBean.myTestInputText}" />
        <!-- Some input elements -->
        <p:commandButton id="myHiddenButton" style="display: none" />
    </h:form>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <h:form id="form2">
        <p:commandButton value="Submit Form1"
            onclick="document.getElementById('myHiddenButton').click();"    
        actionListener="#{myBean.doSomeBackendStuff()}"
            update=":form1" />
    </h:form>
</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My Bean:

```
package de.vwag.flucs.presentation.admin.boundary;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped;

@ViewAccessScoped
@Named("myBean")
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8923580640140500834L;

    private String myTestInputText = "";

    public String getMyTestInputText() {
        return myTestInputText;
    }

    public void setMyTestInputText(String myTestInputText) {
        this.myTestInputText = myTestInputText;
    }

    public void doSomeBackendStuff() {
        // Do Some Backendstuff!
        System.out.println("He hit me! He entered: " + myTestInputText );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the javascript won't work because the client id of the hidden button is not `myHiddenButton` it should be `form1:myHiddenButton`

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the wrong client id. Now it is working with js. But the primefaces way still doesn't work. If i press the the submit button the inputtext field is not submitted to the bean.

Comment: apparently I've made a mistake, see the last answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738871/submit-multiple-forms-with-pcommandbutton

Comment: OR your way it's just fine I think